# Push menu with scroll

Tags: javascript, css, menu, push, nav

I am using a push menu on a website. Here is the test link: http://web553.login-15.loginserver.ch/

But the menu shows only the points, that are in the visible area. The site has more navigation items, that would need to be scrolled. But those points are not displayed. How can I make them visible? I believe it some kind of CSS issue.

Comment: It is a css issue, specifically the height of the element... but i'm seeing if i can work on a fix....

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`overflow: hidden` is applied to `div.panel`.

[Chrome Dev Tools style view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfTgY.png)

[MDN article on overflow property.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Comment: That was the matter - thank you!